# IE tried to get favicon in the root folder and failed

Tags: internet-explorer, favicon

Some IE in my company cannot load the website when trying to get favicon in the root folder (getting 500 error), but other IE and chrome work well

the source code of favicon is

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="../../images/favicon.ico">
```

the browser console show favicon was loaded twice one in the custom folder (../../images/), one in root which failed with 500 error

Comment: Are they all in the same version? (The IE that works and the IE that doesn't work)

Comment: Hi Bruno they are in different version. Our IT support sometimes solves the issue by 'rebuilding IE profiles'. I'm think the version matters but want to know the details thanks

Comment: Hi Winston, I am actually not sure why that is happening. But I think if you update your question to include the versions, that may help to get a better answer.

Comment: Please check the IE browser versions they are using? Besides, it seems that they are using different settings? You could try to use [IEDigest](http://www.regente.de/IEDigest/) to collect and compare the Internet Explorer settings, also, as you said, you could [reset Internet Explorer settings](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/17441/windows-internet-explorer-change-reset-settings).